# How to disable vertical scrolling for jScrollPane?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using the jQuery plugin [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/). I want to disable vertical scrolling for the scrollpanes I set.

How can I do that?

I've checked their website, but they don't have an official API page.

Comment: We wanted to hide horizontal scroll bar on our site and my colleague, the front-end developer, managed to hide it in CSS and Javascirpt.

Comment: I've managed to do this, but jScrollpane disregards it.

Comment: Official [jScrollPane settings](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html) and [jScrollPane API](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They may not have an official api page, but they do have examples that can help. For example, the following page contains a solution to this question: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrows.html

Page javascript

```
$(function()
{
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
});
```

Page CSS

```
/* Styles specific to this particular page */
.scroll-pane
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.horizontal-only
{
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

This appears to explain how to accomplish your goals here.

Comment: My problem is as follows, my scroll area is longer than seems to the user, and I moved the horizontal scrollbar up so as to fool a bit. I need it to be longer because my scrollable content expands a bit on hover, so it needs to simulate an "overflow" effect. I've disabled the jScrollpane and added the following CSS to `.scroll-pane { overflow-y: scroll !important; overflow-x: auto !important; }`. This works perfectly with the native scrollbars, but not jScrollpane.

Comment: It seems that specifying `height: 200px` for `.scroll-pane` was the key here, I made it longer the first time round, and then specifying it exactly 200px made the vertical scrolling disappear.